# UIScrollView is "lagging" when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uiscrollview

After searching a couple of hours, i still got an issue using UIScrollView and Keyboard.
When the keyboard is Showing up i am resizing the ScrollView with the contentInset attribute through a keyboardWillShow method.

I'm using Autolayout with good constraints

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification)
{
   var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
   var keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()  
   keyboardFrame = self.view.convertRect(keyboardFrame, fromView: nil)  
   var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = self.ScrollView.contentInset
   contentInset.bottom = keyboardFrame.size.height
   self.ScrollView.contentInset = contentInset
}
```

Is it an Xcode issue or am i doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "lagging"?

Comment: when i scroll up and down it's not as fast as without keyboard, i don't know really how to describe it

Comment: Are you doing anything in `scrollViewDidScroll` or any other delegate method that's being called as you scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you might want to check if you have "Slow Animations" turned on in your iOS Simulator.

[image: xcode]

If not one possible reason is your macs' speed. Usually every app runs faster on the actual device, then on the simulator. I would suggest you to test-build on a real device.

Comment: Slow animations wasn't checked, but u were right ; it was the simulator, i didn't expect that the simulator could be that slower than device. Thanks !

Comment: No problem, you are a great example of how you should be asking. You showed effort and made clear what your question was all about. :)